# React JS - How to Build different flavours of Web apps using same code via configurations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

I am looking for some inputs on using the same code base for catering to multiple apps (similar apps). For example there is an app A with multiple features and there is app B with reduced features. App B might have some other differences like having less menu items or some options disabled, some additional validations, some changes at form level. What would be the optimized approach to implement this with same codebase?
So far I have thought about below approaches:

1. Feature flags approach to exclude functionality at feature level. If App B does not support any feature of App A, this will be used.
2. Configuration files for rendering menu items/options. Each app will have its configuration.
   I do not want to completely switch to fully dynamic UI which reads the configuration from JSON/XML and renderes everything at runtime. However need an intermediate option which can help in achieving App A and B with same codebase. Please let me know if anyone has worked on similar requirement or if you have any ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited the question. Main question here is to have multiple apps using same code base.